# can haskell compile code or just 'cabal repl --build-depends fmt'?

Tags: haskell, cabal

i can use this to import Fmt in haskell

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\hid-examples-master\hid-examples-master\ch01>cabal repl --build-depends fmt
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-9.6.1 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
...
...
...
Warning: No exposed modules
GHCi, version 9.6.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cabal-repl.-5812\\setcwd.ghci
ghci> import Fmt
ghci>
```

but i cant

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\hid-examples-master\hid-examples-master\ch01>ghc vocab3.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( vocab3.hs, vocab3.o )

vocab3.hs:12:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Fmt’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
   |
12 | import Fmt
   | ^^^^^^^^^^

C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\hid-examples-master\hid-examples-master\ch01>
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\hid-examples-master\hid-examples-master\ch01>
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\hid-examples-master\hid-examples-master\ch01>
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\hid-examples-master\hid-examples-master\ch01>ghc vocab3.hs --build-depends fmt
ghc-9.6.1.exe: unrecognised flag: --build-depends

Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
```

can i use ghc to compile ? i like to compile code cause i think compiler is better than interpreter
or just use cabal to run code ?
can you explain why ?

Comment: Create a `.cabal` file that specifies your `.hs` source file as the target and `fmt` as a dependency. Then use `cabal build`. A convenient way to obtain the `.cabal` file is to run `cabal init`.

Comment: Going by the file paths, it seems you're working with [the examples from the *Haskell in Depth* book](https://github.com/bravit/hid-examples), which are structured as a Cabal project with multiple executables. For instance, `cabal run vocab1` will compile and run the first of the examples in the `ch01` directory. Additional guidance can be found in readme of the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Any "real" development should always be done inside a (Cabal) package. `cabal build` inside a package will run the compiler with the correct options to find any libraries you specify. Once a program is built with `cabal`, it is its own executable that runs without needing `cabal` anymore. It's just that, until you `cabal install` it, the executable is buried very deep in a directory tree, so `cabal run` is the easiest way to *find* the program to run it. You can issue `find dist-newstyle -type f -perm -u+x` to find the actual compiled executable for yourself.

The reason to use `cabal` is that it is impractical to install packages globally (keyed only by name) in the Haskell ecosystem. One week, installing an executable may pull in certain libraries at certain versions. The next week, the libraries may update, and a different executable might want the new versions. Mediating access to packages through a package manager/build system is necessary to avoid getting into messes. This is the same reason Python has Pip and venvs and Java has Maven.

That said, if you *really* want to use GHC directly, the way to do it without making an irreparable mess is

```bash
# assuming you have some code in vocab03.hs
$ cabal install --lib fmt --package-env=./my-env # cabal will download and compile fmt (if necessary), then write out a file that can be used to point GHC at the build product
$ ghc -package-env ./my-env -outputdir build vocab03.hs # direct(!!) compiler invocation
# any "messes" will be contained inside the file ./my-env (i.e. a future cabal install into ./my-env may fail due to conflicting package versions)
# actually, multiple cabal installs into the same environment file was always broken last I checked
# but either way you can always just delete the file and cabal-install again with a new list of packages
```

That is, use `cabal` to build `fmt` and write out a file locating the build result, then use `ghc` to compile your own code on top of that build.

Comment: Instead of `find`, modern `cabal` offers `list-bin`, as in `cabal list-bin <executable-name>`.